# App recommendation or help with install

Tags: software-installation

I need some help or recommendations. I'm a PhD student and I'm getting to the research part of my degree and I'm working with a lot of collections of magnetic field signals.

They are in Midas Blue file format (opened by NextMidas), which for some reason, cant recognize my java jdk install. The file is in the directory, I've triple checked and used "whereis javac", etc. It's there

So I gave up and moved on to Cern ROOT, and also trying Redhawk.

Compiles fail, stuff doesnt work, etc so I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with data files and FFTs, or app recommendations for viewing the raw data in the files, as well as generating the graphs.

Comment: NextMidas works with Midas Blue Files. The [NextMidas](http://nextmidas.techma.com/) project, part of which is embedded in the REDAWK IDE, can be used as a standalone tool in conjunction with the REDHAWK IDE to provide some data analysis capabilities. Requires Java 8+ (openjdk-8-jdk).

Comment: Thanks I'm aware of that, I have Java JDK installed, however NextMidas doesnt recognize it. REDHAWK is throwing a variety of errors on install

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it is an abandoned question.